# How do I copy and paste from bash to vim and vice-versa using only the keyboard?

Tags: windows, linux, bash, vim, putty

Using this command:

http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#vi

I'm able to use vim commands in the bash. But, what I'd like to do is copy and paste from that (bash) into vim and vice-versa.

I know there are other posts on here using the middle mouse button, but I use putty to connect to linux boxes, and the middle mouse performs a selection, just like the left click drag.

I'm not looking for something that will modify my windows clipboard. Selecting in vim is useful for transfering stuff to and from windows, but I'd like a solution that will work both through putty and using a direct terminal.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the copy&paste feature in `screen`.  <kbd>ctrl-[</kbd> to enter copy mode and <kbd>ctrl-]</kbd> to paste.  There are different buffers and the ability to dump to a file.  It's pretty powerful.  The default is to copy lines, but you can curtail by columns join display lines into a single copied line (and other options).  And since you would likely already be in screen when you run vim, you would have the paste buffer available.  I also have hooks to copy the buffer to/from the X clipboard.

Comment: +1 cool feature. documented [here](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/screen-3.9.4/html_chapter/screen_12.html#SEC70)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that can help you, but I have installed a utility called xclip, which shares the X11 clipboard with VIM. I mainly use it to copy and paste between instances of VIM running in different terminal windows.

I typically use xclip with the following mappings, which keep a very similar behaviour to the usual yank and paste commands, but using the clipboard:

```
nmap `yy    :.w !xclip<CR><CR>
vmap `y     :w !xclip<CR><CR>
nmap `p     :.r!xclip -o<CR>
nmap `P     :.-r!xclip -o<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `*` (or `+` in X Windows) registers to reference the system clipboard. Anything yanked-to or pasted-from those registers can be used to cooperate with other applications:

### Cut/Copy examples

**`"*yy`** : copy current line to the system clipbard

**`gg"*yG`** : copy current file to the system clipbard

**`"*dd`** : cut current line to the system clipbard

etc, etc

---

### Paste examples

**`"*p`** : paste the system clipbard

Or in insert mode:

**`i`** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> **`*`**

Or

**`i`** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> **`*`**

(the last one pastes withouth formatting, useful to avoid those ugly pastes from the OS clipboard where each indented line appears more and more shifted)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy from/to the clipboard in both vim and bash using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>ins</kbd>  for copy, and  <kbd>shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>ins</kbd>  for paste.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't appear to work in this context; though, it's a useful contribution.